# Macro-enabled Excel workbook on OneDrive always prompts to save changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

I recently moved a folder that contains many Excel files from the Documents folder of my user profile to OneDrive. I now see two unexpected behaviours:

1. The first time I open a regular Excel workbook (.xlsx) from OneDrive, it is immediately saved (as if I had chosen Save from the File menu) without me doing anything to cause that. This changes the "Date modified" that I see in File Explorer to today's date. If I open the workbook again, there is no automatic save and I can close the workbook without being prompted to save changes.
2. Any time I open a macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm) from OneDrive, I can't close it without being prompted to save changes (even though I made no changes and the workbook contains no volatile functions). Even if I go ahead and save the workbook, the behaviour repeats the next time I open it.

The first is annoying, but as it is a one-time problem, I can live with it. The second appears to be a permanent problem because:

- I want the "Date modified" field to accurately reflect when I really made a change to the file.
- The "Save changes" prompt when closing a file is only useful if it appears only when I made a change.

Note that in Excel's Save Options I have turned **off** "Autosave OneDrive files by default". Also, I have verified that none of the workbooks I am using contain volatile functions (when they are not in OneDrive, I can open them and close them without being prompted to save changes). My OS is Windows 10 64-bit (Version 1909 Build 18363.476). I am using the latest version of Excel from Office 365 (Subscription Product) which I have installed locally. The Excel File > About screen says the Excel version is 1910 (Build 12130.20390), although clicking on "About Excel" claims the version is Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.1230.20232) 32-bit.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or better yet, how to avoid it?

Update:
As suggested by DOBRESCU_Mihai in the comments, I Installed Google Backup and Sync and used it to sync a folder in Documents to my Google Drive. I copied several of the Excel workbooks into that folder and verified that they also appeared in Google Drive. When opening the Excel workbooks from this folder within Documents, I do not have the problems I had when opening them from the local OneDrive folder. This suggests that the problem is specific to OneDrive rather than syncing to cloud storage in general.

Comment: What Version of the _Microsoft_ _Excel_ Static Software Application are you using? Does it have an _AutoSave_ On-Off Button in the Top-Left Corner?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Sorry, I'll edit that in to my question. It is Office 365 that I have installed locally. The Autosave On-Off button appears in the top left corner and is set to Off.

Comment: Can you install [the _Google_ _Drive_ Cloud File Service Provider](https://www.google.com/drive/), @Blackwood, use it instead of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _OneDrive_ Cloud File Service Provider, attempt to recreate this Issue and then come back with a Status Update?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I tried installing Google Backup and Sync and did not experience the problem when opening Workbooks in a local folder that is being synced to the Google Drive. Unfortunately, a significant percentage of my free Google space is already in use, so I would still prefer to use OneDrive.

Comment: By "_trying_", @Blackwood, we assume that you _really_ succeeded in installing the _Backup and Sync from Google_ Cloud Files and Folders Synchronizer. Through "_WorkBooks_", we imagine that you are still referring to _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Office 365_ _Excel_ WorkBooks with WorkSheets for Calculations. It seems that the Issue does not reproduce itself using the _Google_ _Drive_ Cloud Files and Folders Service Provider.

Comment: We would copy the Issue on [the _Microsoft_ _Answers_ _Community_](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=OneDrive&IsSuggestedTerm=false&tab=&isFilterExpanded=false&CurrentScope.ForumName=msoffice&CurrentScope.Filter=&ContentTypeScope=QnA%2CDiscussion%2CArticle#/msoffice/msoffice_excel/QnA,Discussion,Article/1), @Blackwood. Also, we would use the _GetHelp_ Static Software Application (apps:GetHelp) in order to contact the _Microsoft_ Support Teams and ask them about this Issue. Or use [the _Microsoft_ Support Web-Site](https://support.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Also, for the sake of reference, @Blackwood, so that other interested and helping people might come and look at your Issue Details, it would really help us if you could edit your Question Body with the following two pieces of information: **1.** The Version of your Operating System. **2.** The Version of your _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Office 365_ Software Desktop Suite.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai: I'll address your last three comments in order. Yes, I succeeded in installing Google Backup and Sync and found that the problem did not occur with folders that were synced using Google's product. Yes *Workbooks* refers to Microsoft Excel Workbooks. I will contact Microsoft support about this issue. I will update the question with the version of Windows I am using and will attempt to do the same for Office 365 (although Microsoft appears to display different version numbers in different places).

Comment: You did great, @Blackwood. We are quite happy that we did not have to Tele-Guide you through the Procedures that are needed for extracting those pieces of information. Our Operating System Version is itself the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Home_ Non-_N_ Version `1903` (Operating System Build `18362.476`).

Comment: There is no contradiction between the _Microsoft_ _Excel_ Versions that you have read. Our own Software Installation reports both the _Microsoft_ _Excel_ Version `1911` (Build `12228.20332` _Click-to-Run_) _Monthly Channel_ and the _Microsoft_ _Excel for Office 365_ _M.S.O._ (`16.0.12228.20322`) 64-Bit.

Comment: You see, things seem to be related to the Time Factor lately. The `1903` Mark of the Operating System refers to the Month of March of our current year. The `1911` Mark of the _Microsoft_ _Excel_ Static Software Application refers to the Month of November of our current year. The `16.0` must be the Version of `M.S.O.` that must stand for the _Microsoft_ _Office_ Desktop Software Suite.

Comment: So the Latter Version is probably related to the integration of the _Microsoft_ _Excel_ Static Software Application within the _Microsoft_ _Office_ Desktop Software Suite.

Comment: We would still recommend the replication of this Issue Description on the [_Microsoft_ _Answers_ _Community_](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=OneDrive&IsSuggestedTerm=false&tab=&isFilterExpanded=false&CurrentScope.ForumName=msoffice&CurrentScope.Filter=&ContentTypeScope=QnA%2CDiscussion%2CArticle#/msoffice/msoffice_excel/QnA,Discussion,Article/1) Web-Site, as already advised above, since out there the _Microsoft_ Fans know much more about the _Microsoft_ World than ourselves.

Comment: On a second thought, you could also add the Version of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _OneDrive_ Cloud Files and Folders Service Provider, @Blackwood. Something like "_Version_ 2,019 (_Build_ `19.222.1110.0004`)", as it happens to be our own case.